# Check a checkbox when one is checked react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-multiselect-checkboxes

I have 3 checkboxes CheckboxA, CheckboxB, CheckboxC.
If checkboxB or checkboxC are checked, I want checkboxA to be checked as well

basic checkbox example from react-hook-form https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-clarke-y8cjsw?file=/src/App.js:1792-1801

[image]

Comment: what does that mean *If checkboxB or checkboxC are checked, I want checkboxA to be checked as well*. Please be specific.

Comment: Think of it this way, there are 3 checkboxes. When I tick the 2nd or 3rd checkbox, the 1st checkbox will be automatically marked

 I added a picture maybe it will be more understandable  and there is a codesandbox link @NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onChange` you can check if current input is not A and its value is checked so you can update your new value

```
if (option !== "a" && e.target.checked) valueCopy[0] = "a";
```

**Checkboxes**

```
const Checkboxes = ({ options, control, name }) => {
  const { field } = useController({
    control,
    name
  });

  return (
    <>
      {options.map((option, index) => (
        <input
          onChange={(e) => {
            const valueCopy = [...field.value];

            valueCopy[index] = e.target.checked ? e.target.value : null;
            if (option !== "a" && e.target.checked) valueCopy[0] = "a";
            field.onChange(valueCopy);
          }}
          key={option}
          type="checkbox"
          checked={field.value.includes(option)}
          value={option}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

You can check in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-currying-3d7xlp?file=/src/App.js:226-851)

Comment: Hello @iamhuynq
Thanks a lot, it works according to the situation I posted, but it's a bit more complicated because I'm using react-hooks-form with Material-UI. and i could not work the solutions in the answers you gave above with Material Ui. I recreated the code in CodeSandBox. I hope there is a solution

https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-night-3gfto0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ohh, i'll check

Comment: so what i want to do in this case When I tick the 2nd or 3rd checkbox, the 1st checkbox will be automatically marked only for group2 chekboxes

Comment: You can use [setValue](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue). Check in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-platform-7ict5p?file=/src/App.js). Hope it help @IbrahimYolbir

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this on your line 27:

```
(valueCopy[1] === 'b' || valueCopy[2] === 'c') && (valueCopy.shift(), valueCopy.unshift('a'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works according to the situation I posted, but it's a bit more complicated because I'm using react-hooks-form with Material-UI. and i could not work the solutions in the answers you gave above with Material Ui. I recreated the code in CodeSandBox. I hope there is a solution

https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-night-3gfto0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: so what i want to do in this case When I tick the 2nd or 3rd checkbox, the 1st checkbox will be automatically marked only for group2 chekboxes